# How to speed up Pandas to_sql() for writing to Teradata

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

Writing Terabytes of Data to Teradata Database but to_sql() is incredibly slow.  Currently taking ~60 seconds per 100 rows, which means the data is growing much faster than I can write it!    I have approximately 450 columns and hundreds of millions of rows.  Would like to keep the process inside of Python due to all the data cleanup that is occurring (I haven not included that here in order to keep it more simple) and it's easy to automate.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text, update, insert
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

keys = pd.read_csv('C:/dictionary.csv')

fwidths = [4, 6, 8]


for n in range(441):
    fwidths.append(4)
    fwidths.append(2)
    fwidths.append(2)
    fwidths.append(8)


cols = ['ACT_NUMBER', 'Subject_Code', 'Segment']

t = 1
for n in range(441):
    cols.append('KEY{0}'.format(t))
    cols.append('DATA_TYPE{0}'.format(t))
    cols.append('SIGN{0}'.format(t))
    try:
        cols.append(keys.loc[keys.Key_Num == t, 'Name'].item())
    except:
        cols.append('N/A')
    t+=1

conn = create_engine('teradata://username:password')
chunksize = 100

for file_path in glob.glob('C:/files/*.txt'):
     for chunk in pd.read_fwf(file_path,widths = fwidths, names = cols, iterator = True, skiprows=1, chunksize = chunksize):
         start = timer()
         chunk.to_sql('new_table', con=conn, if_exists = 'append', schema='mySchema', index = False, dtype={'ACT_NUMBER': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255), 'Subject_Code': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255), 'Segment': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255)})
         end = timer()
         print('writing chunk time {0}'.format(end - start))
```

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea not to use a load utility supplied by the database vendor for loading large amounts of data. Seems you load lots of (small?) files with the same layout, this is a simple task for Teradata's TPT.